# Index out of range with less than 6 rows of data

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

**Small brief of what i need and what i currently have**

I connect to a database and get my data from it and i get ( Name , LongNumber) and basically i have an event (action) that fires when the event occurs (this action gives me a LongNumber aswell).

I need to compare the LongNumbers between the one i got from the event (action) and the one from my database, and if they are similar i take the name and use it.
for example Hello, Alex ( alex is taken from the database)

**Issue**

I get Index out of range, and using my logic all texts will change what i'm trying to achieve is to change the text to the name of the person that got the Long number the same as the longNumber from the event

**Code: Gettings Data from the database**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MySqlTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{

private static MySqlTestScript _instnace;
public static MySqlTestScript sharedInstance()
{
    return _instnace;
}


string row = "";

public string host = "*****";
public string database = "*******";
public string usrename= "*******";
public string password = "******";

public List<Data> userData = new List<Data>();

 Data data;


void Awake()
{
    _instnace = this;
}


// Use this for initialization
public void Start()
{

    GetDataFromDatabase();
}

public string GetDataFromDatabase()
{
     string myConnectionString = "Server="+host+";Database="+database+";Uid="+usrename+ ";Pwd="+password+";";


    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    MySqlDataReader Reader;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                //rfid_tags.Add (Reader.GetString("UserName"));
                //rfid_tags.Add(Reader.GetString("RFID_Tag"));
                data = new Data(Reader.GetString("UserName"), Reader.GetString("RFID_Tag"));
                userData.Add(data);
                // ws.DomainUrl = reader.GetString("DomainUrl");
                // rfid_tags.Add(Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",");
                // row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
            }

            Debug.Log(row);
        }
    }


    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Debug.Log(x.Message);
        return x.Message;
    }

    connection.Close();
    return row;

}

}

public class Data {

public string username { get; set; }
public string rfid { get; set; }

public Data(string _name, string _rfid)
{
    username = _name;
    rfid = _rfid;
}


public void SetUserName(string _userName) { username = _userName; }
public void SetRFID(string _rfid) { rfid = _rfid; }


}
```

**Code for Comparing the values from the event(action) and showing the text**

```
void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
{
    Debug.Log("OnTagsReported");

   // This event handler is called asynchronously 
    // when tag reports are available.
    // Loop through each tag in the report 
    // and print the data.
     foreach (Tag tag in report)
    {

        Debug.Log(tag.Epc);
    //    Debug.Log(MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().rfid_tags[0]);

            Debug.Log("STEP ONE");
            for (int i = 0; i < MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().userData.Count; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("STEP TWO");
                if (tag.Epc.ToString().Trim() == MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().userData[i].rfid)
                {
                    Debug.Log("STEP THREE");
                    // TODO References the Name 
                    Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() => {

                         namesTxt[i].text = MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().userData[i].username;

                    });

                }
            }
```

As you can see in the Event script it's so unflexible and it gives index out of range if my database has less than 6 rows. I need to make it more friendly and generic

Any help would be appreciated and i hope my question is clear Thank you :)!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174292/discussion-on-question-by-jackson-wells-index-out-of-range-with-less-than-6-rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make more sense:

Database:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MySqlTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{

private static MySqlTestScript _instnace;
public static MySqlTestScript sharedInstance()
{
    return _instnace;
}


string row = "";

public string host = "*****";
public string database = "*******";
public string usrename= "*******";
public string password = "******";

public List<AppUser> users = new List<AppUser>();

void Awake()
{
    _instnace = this;
}


// Use this for initialization
public void Start()
{

    GetDataFromDatabase();
}

public string GetDataFromDatabase()
{
  string myConnectionString = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";Uid=" + usrename + ";Pwd=" + password + ";";

  MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
  MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
  MySqlDataReader Reader;

  try
  {
    connection.Open();
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (Reader.Read())
    {
      users.Add(new AppUser() { 
        username = Reader.GetString("UserName").Trim(),
        rfid = Reader.GetString("longNumbers ").Trim()
      });
    }
  }
  catch (Exception x)
  {
    Debug.Log(x.Message);
    return x.Message;
  }

  connection.Close();
  return row;
}
}
```

Data object:

```
public Class AppUser 
{ 
  public string rfid { get; set; } 
  public string username { get; set; } 
}
```

Event/data comparison:

```
void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
{
  Debug.Log("OnTagsReported");

  // This event handler is called asynchronously 
  // when tag reports are available.
  // Loop through each tag in the report 
  // and print the data.
  foreach (Tag tag in report)
  {
    Debug.Log(tag.Epc);
    List<AppUser> appUsers = MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().users;
    int numUsers = appUsers.Count;
    Debug.Log(numUsers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
    {
      if (tag.Epc.ToString().Trim() == appUsers[i].rfid)
      {
        // TODO References the Name 
        Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() => {
          if (i < namesTxt.Count) namesTxt[i].Text = appUsers[i].username; //assumes textnames is a "List" of textboxes and is already populated with instances of text1, text2 text3 etc. The if is just to guard against there being more rows in the DB than textboxes
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really weird what's happening.. I'm adding debugs and none of them are executing. The text isn't changing and im not getting any errors

I have added a debug inside the foreach loop
added One inside the for loop
and one inside the condition that is inside the for loop and finally one when text change

Comment: You mean the `foreach (Tag tag in report)`? Obvious question...do you have any items in the `report` list?

Comment: Inside OnTagsReported

Comment: Yes i do have around 2 and more items

Comment: `    Debug.Log(tag.Epc);
` Prints 2 and more

Comment: Also     Debug.Log(numUsers);
 deosn't execute

Comment: Debug.Log(tag.Epc); is the last thing that get's executed

Comment: if `Debug.Log(tag.Epc);` executes but `Debug.Log(numUsers);` doesn't, then presumably the application threw an exception in between? There's not really any other sensible explanations. There's no change of flow in the code which could otherwise stop it from running. Step through the code line by line using Visual Studio in debug mode and wait for an exception or other problem. Inspect the value of `numUsers` just in case it's somehow `null` or something.

Comment: It's really werid.. **Error CS1703 Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files\Unity 2018.1.0b13\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.7.1-api\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. Assembly-CSharp D:\Projects\NewXarray\CSC 1 Active** I'm getting this although i delete the duplicated. and re-created project from zero again.. i cant debug ;(.

Comment: 29 Errors like this all of them different dll's so i went to the reference and delete them. refresh and same errors came back.. so i created new project. and same thing.. it's not allowing me to debug in visual studio

Comment: Hi @ADyson everything is working fine expect the text, it doesn't change. it returns null.. after debug the nameTxt length is 6 and i is 4 you have a condition that says if i < nameTxt.Length after that i have a Debug but that debug isn't executing this is the last thing im stuck at

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this is to wrap each of your cases in another `if` statement to check if the database has that many rows

```
if (MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().longNumbers.Length > 1) {
    if (tag.Epc.ToString().Trim() == MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().longNumbers[0].ToString()) {

        if(MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().userNames[0] != null)
           txt1.text = "Hello "+ MySqlTestScript.sharedInstance().userNames[0];
        }
    }
}
else {
    txt1.text = "";
}
```

This will avoid your index out of range exception. In each wrapping case you will need to increment the comparison to be 1, 2, 3, etc.

It is not the prettiest solution but will avoid the exception. Another option would be to wrap in a try-catch block. Again not the prettiest but would accomplish the task.